# Schedule task to run without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, e-commerce

I'm working on an e-commerce site where users can rent out equipment, and I need to schedule the payment using Stripe. I'm using `setupIntents`, which uses a `customerId`, which I'm storing on my server, and from there, I can charge the account from my server. Stripe doesn't support scheduling payments using an API. AFAIK you have to do it yourself.

I don't want to use timeouts, because if I ever have to do a server restart, the payments won't happen. I also need to send two emails, one to the vendor, and another to the customer, which aren't as important as the payments. The hosting platform I'm on sometimes does regular restarts, which is another reason I can't use timeouts.

What I'm looking for is something that can execute a `js` file, even if my server is not running, and take parameters as well.

Comment: sounds like you should have a cron job

Comment: I know about cron jobs, but I need to execute js, and not bash or anything. I also need to take parameters from something as well

Comment: So look into it. Plenty examples of cron jobs in node js

Comment: Create a task that runs every x minutes, run a check against the db for things needed billed.

Comment: ig a cron job running a node script with parameters in the script call might work.